# How to initialize Redux state with the response of an asynchronous request

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am building a **React-Redux** app that must load a list from an api from the beginning. I have been able to make it work initializing the state with a hard coded list, so far:

`reducers/Catalogs.js`

```
import {
  GET_CATALOGS,
  SHOW_MESSAGE,
  HIDE_MESSAGE,
  GET_CATALOGS_SUCCESS
} from 'constants/ActionTypes';

const INIT_STATE = {
  loader: false,
  alertMessage: '',
  showMessage: false,
  catalogsList: ['uno', 'dos'] /// Hard coded initialization that must be from an api
};

export default (state=INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CATALOGS_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loader: false,
        catalogsList: action.payload
      }
    }
    case SHOW_MESSAGE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        alertMessage: action.payload,
        showMessage: true,
        loader: false
      }
    }
    case HIDE_MESSAGE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        alertMessage: '',
        showMessage: false,
        loader: false
      }
    }
    case GET_CATALOGS: {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I know from readings that reducers shouldn't make asynchronous calls or dispatch actions for instance, so I am using **redux-sagas** in order to manage asynchronous calls.

`sagas/Catalogs.js`

```
import {all, call, fork, put, takeEvery} from "redux-saga/effects";
import {catalogs} from 'backend/Catalogs';
import {GET_CATALOGS} from "constants/ActionTypes";
import {getCatalogs, getCatalogsSuccess, showCatalogsMessage} from 'actions/Catalogs';

const getCatalogsRequest = async (group) =>
  await catalogs.getCatalogs(group)
    .then(catalogsList => catalogsList)
    .catch(error => error);

function* getCatalogsListFromRequest({payload}) {
  const {group} = payload;
  try {
    const catalogsList = yield call(getCatalogsRequest, group);
    if (catalogsList.message) {
      yield put(showCatalogsMessage(catalogsList.Message));
    } else {
      yield put(getCatalogsSuccess(catalogsList))
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(showCatalogsMessage(error));
  }
}

export function* getCatalogsList() {
  yield takeEvery(GET_CATALOGS, getCatalogsListFromRequest);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(getCatalogsList)
  ]);
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to use it to initialize the state because such initialization is not part of an action.

Comment: Dispatching action from ComponentDidMount() will trigger the action which in turn will initiate the async action and will update your store once you get the state from API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to create `componentDidMount()` for your main `App` component and dispatch `GET_CATALOGS` action inside it, which should request data on mount your app (on init) and update store.

Comment: Great, it works, thanks! Only that I found that it works better for me (I don't know if it is so in any case) with `componentWillMount()`

Comment: @HuLuViCa `componentWillMount` is deprecated in the latest React, should stick with `componentDidMount`

Comment: Or check out `getDerivedStateFromProps`